# How do I justify these nontheorems in the absence of the Existence Property for $PA$

Tags: lo.logic, peano-arithmetic

Let $\Pi$ be the provability predicate for $PA$. I want to conclude that $PA\nvdash\exists x(\alpha(x)\wedge\lnot\Pi\ulcorner \alpha(\overset{.}{x}) \urcorner)$ and $PA\nvdash\exists x(\lnot \alpha(x)\wedge\Pi\ulcorner \alpha(\overset{.}{x})\urcorner)$. If I were allowed to existentially instantiate enough I could achieve this. How may I in the absence of the existence property for $PA$?

Comment: By using the fact that the provability predicate is a $\Sigma^0_1$ formula, and that PA is 1-consistent?

Comment: The first property implies the consistency of PA, hence it is not provable by Gödel. The second property is false in the standard model $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes. But how do I prove by a reductio that $PA \vdash\bot$ if either $PA \vdash\exists x(\alpha(x)\wedge\lnot\Pi\ulcorner \alpha(\overset{.}{x}) \urcorner)$ or $PA \vdash\exists x(\lnot \alpha(x)\wedge\Pi\ulcorner \alpha(\overset{.}{x})\urcorner)$?

Comment: (Anyway, perhaps I should just remain content with your remarks here and let it be at that.)

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you want. However, note that the second assumption does not imply $PA\vdash\bot$ in a weaker metatheory like PA itself. The unprovability is equivalent to the consistency of the uniform reflection principle for PA, which is *much* stronger than the consistency of PA itself.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek That is a good point. So we may conclude$PA\nvdash\exists x(\lnot \alpha(x)\wedge\Pi\ulcorner \alpha(\overset{.}{x})\urcorner)$ (as I want) in a metatheory that includes $PA$ and the assertion that a schema for uniform reflection may consistently be added to $PA$. It seems that we by symmetry may invoke the possibility of consistently adding a $schema$ for semantic completenes  ($\forall x(\phi(x)\to\Pi\ulcorner\phi(\overset{.}{x})\urcorner)$) to justify  that $PA\nvdash\exists x(\alpha(x)\wedge\lnot\Pi\ulcorner \alpha(\overset{.}{x}) \urcorner)$.

Comment: There is not much point in discussing the schema of completeness in classical arithmetic, as it is equivalent to just $\Pi\ulcorner\bot\urcorner$. It is, however, interesting in the context of intuitionistic arithmetic, see https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(82)90024-9 .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, I agree that there is not much point beyond establishing the nonderivability I was asking for. I used precisely the term "semantic completeness" here because Craig Smorynski used this in his Theorem 4.3.1 in The Incompleteness Theorem in Handbook of Mathematical Logic. Thank you for the interesting link to the article of Visser!